# Typescript: Infer generic type by checking string value

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have types like this:

```
export type NotificationType = 'comment' | 'like' | 'message' | 'follow' | unknown

type MessageBody<T extends NotificationType> = T extends 'comment'
  ? {
      body: string
      threadId: string
      projectId: string
    }
  : T extends 'like'
  ? {
      resourceId: string
      resourceType: 'project' | 'projectVersion' | 'thread' | 'comment'
    }
  : T extends 'message'
  ? {
      body: string
      chatId: string
    }
  : T extends 'follow'
  ? {}
  : never

export type Message<T extends NotificationType = unknown> = {
  channel: string
  message: MessageBody<T> & {
    type: T
  }
  timetoken: string | number
  uuid?: string
  publisher?: string
}
```

What I want to do now is infer the type of `T` by checking the property `message.type` without having to specify the type of `T` beforehand, so something like this:

```
function checkMessage(message: Message) { // No generic type given
  switch (message.message.type) {
    case 'comment':
      message.message.body // infers to MessageBody<'comment'>
  }
}
```

But with this approach I get an error on the switch statement with:
`Property 'type' does not exist on type 'never'.`

Which probably comes from the usage of `unknown` inside the `NotificationType`. How can I have the generic optional and still infer the type by checking the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd willing to bet that `NotificationType` should only be a string. Hence, using `unknown` is not the best idea for representing unknown string type. It is much better to use just refular  `string` type. However, using `string` type with other literal strings like `comment` and `follow` will clash them to just a `string`. This is why t is better to use `string & {}`.

Also, I have used map data stucture instead conditional type `MessageBody`.

```js
export type KnownType = 'comment' | 'like' | 'message' | 'follow'

export type UnknownType = string & {}

type NotificationType = KnownType | UnknownType

type MessageMap = {
  comment: {
    body: string
    threadId: string
    projectId: string
  },
  like: {
    resourceId: string
    resourceType: 'project' | 'projectVersion' | 'thread' | 'comment'
  },
  message: {
    body: string
    chatId: string
  },
  follow: {}
}

type MessageBase = {
  channel: string
  timetoken: string | number
  uuid?: string
  publisher?: string
}

type MessageBody<T extends KnownType> = { message: MessageMap[T] & { type: T } } & MessageBase

export type ComputeMessage<T extends NotificationType> = T extends KnownType ? MessageBody<T> : never

function checkMessage<MessageType extends NotificationType>(message: ComputeMessage<MessageType>) {

  switch (message.message.type) {
    case 'comment':
      message.message.projectId // ok
      message.message.threadId // ok
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WzAB1m)